# Why add zero bias in neural networks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

Code from the [MNIST tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist.py#L57-L73):

```
  with tf.name_scope('hidden1'):
    weights = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([IMAGE_PIXELS, hidden1_units],
                            stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(IMAGE_PIXELS))),
        name='weights')
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden1_units]),
                         name='biases')
    hidden1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(images, weights) + biases)
  # Hidden 2
  with tf.name_scope('hidden2'):
    weights = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([hidden1_units, hidden2_units],
                            stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(hidden1_units))),
        name='weights')
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden2_units]),
                         name='biases')
    hidden2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden1, weights) + biases)
```

It seems all the biases are zero. What's point in adding them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking at network initialisation code. This is the network before training. The random `weights` values don't map to any useful function at that stage. Instead they are randomised to prevent each artificial neuron learning the same thing, because back propagation is deterministic, you usually need something that breaks symmetry between neurons within the same layer. Otherwise each training example would generate exactly the same gradients for each weight, and everything would change in lockstep.

Here:

```
biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden1_units]),
                         name='biases')
```

`biases` is a variable. It will change later, during training. You could start with random values if you like (similar to weights), and the training will still work almost identically to the example. However, the random weights are already enough in practice to prevent outputs copying each other, so setting bias to zero is simplest approach.

Take a look at the bias values after some training, and you will see they are all different.